# Webpack sideEffects wont remove unused function

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundler, side-effects

In the babel-loader iam declaring side-effects to false which means that any unused function should be removed from the bundle. But in my case logFour function remains.

**util.js**

```
export function logThree() {
  console.log(3);
}
export function logFour() {
  console.log(4);
}

logThree();

logFour();
```

**index.js**

```
 import { logThree } from "./util";
logThree();
```

**bundle.js**

```
(() => {
  "use strict";
  function o() {
    console.log(3);
  }
  o(), console.log(4), o();
})();
```

**webpack**

```
module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  entry: ["./src/index"],
  devtool: "source-map",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve("dist/"),
    publicPath: "/public/assets/",
    filename: "main.js",
  },
  optimization: {
    usedExports: true,
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: "./src",
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
        sideEffects: false,
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: That is because when you import utils the function is called

Comment: All the js you are using here have side effects, since they call functions. 'pure' modules only have import/export rules. Yours are currently not tree shakeable.

Comment: @LucaReghellin Your argument isn't correct either. The `console.log(4)` is now inlined in the output bundle and this actually means `logFour` got removed. By setting `sideEffects: false,`, webpack will skip the checking (in fact, webpack/minimizer cannot check it precisely, that's why we need to manually mark them as side-effect free). I will remove my "answer" below because at the time I was also learning the concept.

Comment: The two calls in utils.js should still be called after tree-shaking because even if it does have side-effect, webpack will not know because it simply trusts our setting of `sideEffects: false,`. Think of it this way: If it can know whether our marking is wrong, then we don't have to mark it in the first place :)